# Can't validate email in the backend?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this regular expression to validate emails for signin and signup and it seems it doesn't work, i used two regular expressions to validate email but both failed to validate '.com' in the email address

regular expression 1

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
```

regular expression 2

```
 /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

Both regular expressions succeeded to detect the wrong email till the letter c in `'.com'` so if i wrote an email like this

```
const regEx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
if('goodboy@gmail.co'.match(regEx)) {
   console.log('valid email') // valid email
}
```

so this is a valid email, and for sure it is not

If i wrote an email like this

```
goodboy@gmail.c  //wrong email
```

both can detect it successfully as a wrong email

What is the problem in the two regular expressions, How to solve it?

Comment: What is your expected result?, You need to only valid email addresses with .com extension?  if so go with this `^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.com$ `

Comment: i need to validate emails, so i don't want  goodbody@google.co pass but only goodbody@gmail.com

Comment: @CodeEagle : use validation e-mail instead

Comment: both regex on check if it looks like a valid email adress, but they dont know about existing domains or mail inboxes. you can only check this by sending the user a mail with a verification link.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov sorry i don't understand what you mean

Comment: what Yevgen is talking about is send a verification email to the user after the registration process. if they put it in an invalid email they wont receive the email

Comment: @CodeEagle ".co" is a valid toplevel domain. This one belongs to Colombia. At the end of your expression you allowed with `{2,4}` a range from two till fore letters.

Comment: ah, i thought it is not valid, my bad!, thanks,  @Reporter

Comment: There also exist TLDs much longer than merely 4 characters. You’re falling into the typical trap of trying to validate something you really don’t know the rules of, which will ultimately lead to users not being able to use their legitimate email addresses…

Comment: The best way to validate an email address is to send an email and check the return value. 
 Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: Asking for email regex is beating an undead horse back to death again, then resurrecting it to beat it some more.